# Finding probability with dependent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, puzzle

Suppose train on line A arrives in time uniformly distributed between 0 and 4mins, train on line B arrives in time uniformly distributed between 0 and 6 mins, and furthermore the time interval between A and B arrival is uniformly distributed between 0 and 4.

a. What is the probability train on line A arrives first

b. What is the probability you wait less than 2 mins for one of the trains to arrive.

Here's how I approached this question,

Let $A : $ arrival time for train on line A $\sim U(0,4)$,
$B : $ arrival time for train on line B $\sim U(0,6)$

and it is given that $A-B \sim U(-4,4)$

a. $P(A<B) = P(A-B<0) = \frac{1}{2}$

b. This is where I'm stuck, $P(\mathrm{min}(A,B) \leq 2) = 1 - P(A>2, B>2)$

But I'm not sure how I'd go about computing $P(A>2, B>2)$ any help or hint is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Even though this post hasn't got many views, I am anyway writing here as I've got the answer and might be help some other people who see it in future and are confused just like me

It seems to me that problem statement isn't stated very well, because you cannot have distributions satisfying all the conditioned mentioned in the problem, thus the premise itself is not possible to begin with.